# How do I do #nullable enable in an aspnetcore razor view page (.cshtml)

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, nullable-reference-types

Possible Duplicate, but I've been unable to find anything on this.

I have an asp.net core MVC project, which makes use of normal views using Razor.

I have some ViewModel objects with nullable reference types, and I'm using the C# 8 null-safety feature to mark those appropriately (e.g. `string? Name`)

My problem is, when I use those variables in a `cshtml` file, as strongly typed Models, the null-safety isn't applied because I haven't enabled it for the file.

If it were a `.cs` file, I'd stick `#nullable enable` at the top, but what can I do for razor pages?

---

Update to clarify: If possible, I would like null-safety warnings on all @code blocks throughout the razor file. [Tân's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64640554/234) shows how to enable it for a specific block, but I'd like it for something like this

```
<span>@Model.Name.ToUpper()</span>
```

Specifically, I'd like a warning on Name.ToUpper() as Name is nullable and I didn't use the ? operator when calling ToUpper

Comment: why you want to have it in your view ? view can handel null values, do you get error if you have null value?

Comment: I want the compiler to give me warnings when I use some nullable variable unsafely.

For example if I do this in my view: `@User.Name.ToLower()`

That will crash if Name is null, as I should have done `@User.Name?.ToLower()` or null-checked it first. #nullable will give additional warnings there, and I'd like them in the views if possible

Answer (score 6):

There isn't enough information in your question to say *what you need to do* (such as: adding some package(s), removing some package(s)...)

But by default, [Razor syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1) supports for [#nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references), you can use it inside `@{}` block.

Example:

```
@{
    #nullable enable
    string name1 = User.Identity.Name.ToLower();
    #nullable disable

    // compiler won't complain anything here...
    string name2 = User.Identity.Name.ToLower();
}
```

Test:

> [image: 1]

My `csproj` file what I've used to test:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the error CS8669:

> The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in
> code within a '#nullable' annotations context. Auto-generated code
> requires an explicit '#nullable' directive in source.

For this code inside a razor file:

```
<fluent-search @ref=Element
               value=@Value
               current-value="@BindConverter.FormatValue(CurrentValue)"
               @onchange="@(EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString))"
               @oninput="@(EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString))"
               @attributes="AdditionalAttributes">
    @ChildContent
</fluent-search>
```

You can then solve it like this:

```
@{#pragma warning disable CS8669}
<fluent-search @ref=Element
               value=@Value
               current-value="@BindConverter.FormatValue(CurrentValue)"
               @onchange="@(EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString))"
               @oninput="@(EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString))"
               @attributes="AdditionalAttributes">
    @ChildContent
</fluent-search>
@{#pragma warning restore CS8669}
```

This will **not** work:

```
@{#nullable enable}
<fluent-search @ref=Element
               value=@Value
               current-value="@BindConverter.FormatValue(CurrentValue)"
               @onchange="@(EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString))"
               @oninput="@(EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString))"
               @attributes="AdditionalAttributes">
    @ChildContent
</fluent-search>
@{#nullable disable}
```

Comment: The pragma warning disable CS8669 means that within that block, I can use `string?` without the compiler complaining. But that's not the goal. Rather, I *want* the compiler to complain when I'm *not* using `string?`. Essentially, I want null safety to work properly, not disable it.